# Reload/Refresh an ABPersonViewController

Tags: ios4, contacts, reload, abpeoplepickerview, page-refresh

In my app, users can view and edit their Address Book contacts. Right now, I'm trying to support iOS 4 backgrounding.

Here's my problem. If a user is viewing a contact, say "John Appleseed" in my app, the user can then switch to the iPhone Address Book, open "John Appleseed," and change his contact info. If the user then switches back to my app, my app's view of John Appleseed is now out of date. I want this view to refresh with the new info. Obviously, the user can close and reopen the contact in-app (or the app can do this programmatically), but this is a less than ideal user experience.

I know this is possible the other way around i.e. user edits contact in-app and switches to the iPhone Address Book and the view auto updates.

I already know how to detect if a change has happened, but I want to be able to refresh the view. I am using an ABPersonViewController. Unfortunately, since this isn't an instance of UITableViewController, I can't just do `[self.tableView reloadData]`

Thanks in advance for any help on the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know how to get the new contact information as ABRecordRef, then try

```
yourABPersonViewController.displayedPerson = yourNewABRecordRef;
[yourABPersonViewController.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: turns out this works in iOS 4.2 and later. I'm guessing my problem was a bug in previous iOS versions. Thanks!